# Regular expression how to get value in shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, regular-expression

I have to write a shell script to get value from a string, something like:

```
string="abcdef" pathName
```

How can I use `grep` command with the use of regular expression to get "pathName"?

Comment: using bash ?   ....

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep has the `--only-matching` option:

```
echo 'string="abcdef" pathName' |grep --only-matching "pathName"
```

will output "pathName".

Update with more info on the required pattern:

```
echo 'string="abcdef" pathName' |grep --only-matching "[[:graph:]]*$"
```

Here `[[:graph:]]` is the [character class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) of all non-space characters,
`*` means zero-or-more of the preceding pattern, `$` means end-of-line.
So the pattern matches the longest sequence of non-space characters at the end of the line.

Comment: but I don't know what exactly "pathName" is. It can be a sequence of characters anything. In particular, I need a regular expression to get it.

Comment: You need to know *something* about the input string in order to construct a regex. If there are no space characters in "pathName" you could use `"[[:graph:]]*$"`.

Comment: thank you very much... can you explain it to me ?

Comment: @minhcat_vo I've updated my answer to explain the pattern.